# summarize extent of pooling or shrinkage in multilevel models estimated with lmer()

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, pooling

I am using `lmer()` in the "lme4" package to estimate multilevel models. The models include random intercepts for each group in my data. To fix ideas, here is a toy example:

```
library(lme4)
data(iris)
foo <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + (1 | Species), 
            data = iris)
```

I would like to summarize the extent to which models like this shrink the estimates of the intercepts toward the grand mean of all intercepts, relative to the estimates that I would get from a simpler model, estimated with `lm()`, that includes dummy variables for each group. How may I do this?

In their book, Gelman and Hill (2007, 477-80) refer to this summary statistic as a "pooling factor" and they note that others sometimes speak of a related "shrinkage factor." In their notation, the intercepts are $\theta_k = \hat{\theta}_k + \epsilon_k$ for $k = 1, \ldots, K$. They suggest estimating a summary of the extent to which the variance of the residuals $\epsilon_k$ is reduced by the pooling of the multilevel model:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\V}{V}
L = 1 - \frac{\V_\limits{k=1}^KE(\epsilon_k)}{E\left(\V_\limits{k=1}^K \epsilon_k\right) }.
$$
They give instructions for computing this quantity in BUGS. But is there a relatively simple way to do it in R?

Perhaps the numerator in the equation above corresponds to `sigma(foo)^2`, but I'm not sure of that. And I don't have good ideas about how to compute the denominator. Can this information be extracted from objects created by `lmer()`?

I've looked through CrossValidated and haven't found any posts on this point.

Comment: It is not clear whether your looking a mathematical formula or a numerical result. For the latter, you can simply compare `coef(foo)` versus `coef(loo)`, where `loo <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ 0 + Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)`. The former will be the difference between the equations for the corresponding estimators. Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 3):

Fleshing out Dimitris' comment, you can look at this by considering the estimates you get from `lmer` and `lm`. Using your `lmer` model, we can ask for the estimated intercepts and slopes with the `coef()` function. The intercept listed in `coef()` is based on the overall (fixed effect/grand mean) intercept plus/minus each group's random effect deviation off the fixed intercept:

```
coef(foo)
$Species
           (Intercept) Sepal.Width
setosa        2.277601   0.7971543
versicolor    3.726677   0.7971543
virginica     4.214224   0.7971543
```

Now you can compare these to the intercepts (means) you get from an OLS model with dummy variables for each of the `Species`:

```
summary(foo_fe)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ -1 + Sepal.Width + as.factor(Species), 
    data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.30711 -0.25713 -0.05325  0.19542  1.41253 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Sepal.Width                    0.8036     0.1063   7.557 4.19e-12 ***
as.factor(Species)setosa       2.2514     0.3698   6.089 9.57e-09 ***
as.factor(Species)versicolor   3.7101     0.3010  12.326  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(Species)virginica    4.1982     0.3223  13.027  < 2e-16 ***
```

So the shrinkage going on with this data is not extensive likely because each of the groups has the same (rather large) number of observations and also because the level 2 (`Species`) intercept variance is much higher than the level 1 (within `Species`) variance:

```
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Species  (Intercept) 1.0198   1.010   
 Residual             0.1918   0.438   
Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3
```